# Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<any[]>>' is not assignable to type '(values?: string) => void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, react-hook-form

I'm very new to typescipt and trying to make a basic pin-input page. [Sandbox link for my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-meadow-eisq5?file=/src/App.tsx) . Although it is working, I'm getting this error for onChange function at line 10:

> Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<any[]>>' is not assignable to type '(values?: string) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'values' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<any[]>'.ts(2322)

I'm importing [react-hook-pin-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-pin-input) and I'm unable to find any demos to use onChange in ts. Please help me re-write onChange such that valueE becomes the value that is being entered. Source for react-hook-pin-input can be found here - https://github.com/elevensky/react-hook-pin-input

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notice that `onChange` is of type `(values?: string) => void` and you passing `setValueE` which is of type `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[]>>` which means `setValueE` accepts `string[]` and you passing a `string` type on writing `onChange={setValueE}`.

It works for you only by mistake, because you init `valueE` with string but then change it to `string` type, for it to work as expected do something like:

```
export default function App() {
  const [valueE, setValueE] = useState<string[]>([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>验证码</h1>
      <PinInput
        fields={4}
        values={valueE}
        onChange={(string) => setValueE([...string])}
      />
      <div> {valueE} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit blissful-resonance-v3lwz]

Comment: This solution worked for me, with a little different was that I add "as string[]" after ...string, ====> [...string as string[]]

Answer (score 2):

Note that you may see a similar error if you use a normal `input` component with `useState`. The cause is that the `onChange` property expects a function that takes an `event`, while the actual value of the input field would be `event.target.value`.

So instead of directly writing `onChange={setName}`, you would need to do something like:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  return(
                   <input
                      type="text"
                      value={name}
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        setName(event.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
    )
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, almost like your problem, I had

```
const [code, setCode] = useState('');
<TextField
   label="code"
   value={code}
   onChange={setCode}
/>
```

Typescript didn't appreciate it, the type of the dispatcher and the eventHandler were not the same.

> Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction>' is not assignable to type
> 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>'

Then I came up with this wrapper function, which fixes the problem.

```
function withEvent(func: Function): React.ChangeEventHandler<any> {
  return (event: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
    const { target } = event;
    func(target.value);
  };
}

// then wrap your function with it
<TextField label="code" value={code} onChange={withEvent(setCode)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, same problem, I had

Try assign the state using the following method, this works for me ,hope will help others

```
let code: IUser;
let setCode: any;
[code, setCode] = useState('');
```

Comment: You shouldn't say I have this problem, and etc. Your answer should explain in detail